# Who are known Wireless Networks Stored, and how does auto connect work?

Tags: scripting, wifi, wpa-supplicant, netctl, iw

I'm trying to build a script that *auto connects* to a given network (providing ESSID and Passphrase) and I want to store them, so when ever it's not connected, It searches for the given network, connects.

The problem is that I know there is like a *de facto* uniform way of saving the known networks as *Network Manager* does, but I can't find it explicitly.

I want to save any kind of network and the script will determine the method of connection (if `wpa_supplicant` or `iw-tools`, should I use `netctl`)

So the question is: Where can I find this documentation? or What would be the best way to do it (System or User level)?

Or if there is a tool that allows me to connect to any network with approximately the same procedure?

I'm using *Arch* `<- This is a Meme`

But I'm interested on this script working also with `FreeBSD`.

Comment: Why do you need a script to do this? All the Linux/Unix OS's I can think of do this already if you check that option in the networks setup.

Comment: I want to integrated with `dmenu` and `i3blocks` so the on click events on the i3blocks component, launches a the dmenu script that is runned by this script that I'm trying to write. I want to move away from the NetworkManager Applet.

Comment: OK, I understand a little better now.

Comment: I've been checking right now, If I do it with netctl, it's easy, but It won't work in FreeBSD (because netctl doesn't run, not that I know off)

Comment: Welcome , The Known AP should be set (stored) under `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`,  see [31.3.4.1.3.1. WPA-PSK](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/network-wireless.html) you need a configuration file `wpa_supplicant.conf`, the `wpa_supplicant` and `dhclient` command to connect.

Comment: There is something I find a little bit confusing from the documentation (in general)
`wpa-supplicant` also helps you connect to `WEP` or `Open` networks? Because I can't find where is stated clearly (not man, not arch wiki), the wikis, always explain a different method for `WEP` or `Open`.